# How to transfer the data from windows7 machine to windows 2003 server using ANT script or batch script?

Tags: apache, batch-file, ant, batch-processing

I am using windows7 machine,I would like to know how to transfer the data from local machine to windows2003 server and create directory in to target machine through ant script and batch script..

Comment: This is a sysadmin issue. You'll either need a SSH service install on the windows2003 server or setup a shared drive. Neither of these can be done by ANT, once present they can of course be used by ANT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most systems have an admin share defined. Your `C:` drive is located at `\\locahost\C$`. Replace `localhost` with the name of your target system.

You should run `net use n: \\servername\c$` to establish a connection. If you are not in a domain, you will need to specify username and a password for the connection.

Once you map it, you can treat it like a local drive in your scripts in most situations. Then use whatever tool you are comfortable with to move the files. `robocopy` is a good one for this.